What is the Mapperly equivalent of AfterMap method in Automapper?
I'm trying to replace AutoMapper with Mapperly in our project due to the latter's performance. However, I'm facing difficulty while replacing AutoMapper with Mapperly because I can't find any equivalent of AfterMap() method of AutoMapper in Mapperly. What is the workaround available in Mapperly for this scenario?
